# Exporting XML EDL from Premiere to Davinci Resolve

Tags: premiere, color-grading, davinci-resolve, export

What is the best way to successfully export an EDL from Premiere to Davinci Resolve?
Currently I export a Final Cut Pro XML, but whenever I import into Davinci, there are often errors with scale and speed, if any changes have been made to the size of the source footage.. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Fcp `.xml`  is limited in features. Although more powerful than other [EDL types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_decision_list), most of Premiere's transformation and animation properties are not supported. You can read more about its capabilities [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FinalCutProX/Reference/FinalCutProXXMLFormat/EventsandProjects/EventsandProjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011227-CH12-SW1). However it appears *Premiere CC* neither exports the xml file as recommended by *Apple* nor in its latest version.

I'd suggest *collapse your timeline* and make sure there are no nested clips. Then save your timeline as `.xml` (at least for reference) and replace all faulty shots in *Resolve*, if required. Alternatively you can export the whole clip from *Premiere* via any [production codec](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17202/6685) or ideally as image sequence (`.exr`, `.dpx`, whatever you like depending on your color management workflow) and use Resolve`s [*Scene Cut Detection*](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/speed-color-workflow-using-scene-cut-detection/) function to chop the imported clip into multiple shots automatically.